# CompileSwift normal arm64 when using `xcodebuild` to archive

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcodebuild, xcarchive

Issue: getting the following error in terminal when archiving

`The following build commands failed:`

`CompileSwift normal arm64`

`CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler`

Steps to reproduce:
`xcodebuild -workspace playmule.xcworkspace -scheme playmule -sdk iphoneos -archivePath ~/Desktop/playmule.xcarchive -configuration playmule archive`

The following are a bunch of lines before ** ARCHIVE FAILED ** : (see below)

> /Users/ss/Desktop/playmule-ios/playmule/Utility/NetworkManager.swift:174:25: error: type 'Constants.Api' has no member 'BaseUrl'; did you mean 'resetUrl'?
>           let urlString = Constants.Api.BaseUrl + Constants.Api.currentVersion + Constants.Api.resendSMSEndpoint
>                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~
>                                         resetUrl

This same error is repeated for the same static variable.
The variable is confirmed to be present in the struct as below:

```
struct Constants {
  struct Api {
    static let BaseUrl = "https://some-valid-url.com/dev/"
  }
}
```

EDIT: I am able to run this project on a device and a simulator. So the issue is unrelated to code semantics

Comment: please paste the  relevant bunch of lines on your question.

Comment: updated post, it is just one line.. the pattern is the same and it repeats 19 times, but it is always the same variable `BaseUrl` replace with `resetUrl`

Comment: are your sure you have all curly braces `{` and `}` done correctly. Make sure each opening has a closing to any block of code. Take your time

Comment: Are you able to install the debug build in Real Device(armv64)?

Comment: @ShahrukhAlam yes, I am able to install and run this on a real device as well as a simulator

Comment: Hmm weird, Code looks fine to me, did you try just to build if that gives the same error:

`xcodebuild clean -workspace YOUR_WORKSPACE.xcworkspace -scheme YOUR_SCHEME`

Comment: @asdiu did you solve this ?

Comment: Hello @asdiu I had the same issue today, used an another struct in other struct. Everything was working only when I achieved it I had this error like yours. I could not find any solution instead removed struct

Answer (score 1):

I made a small tweak to my `xcodebuild` command with `-parallelizeTargets` to resolve build errors for projects with frameworks/linked dependency targets:

```
xcodebuild -workspace playmule.xcworkspace -scheme playmule -sdk iphoneos -archivePath ~/Desktop/playmule.xcarchive -parallelizeTargets archive
```

Note that the above flag also helps compile other actions with xcodebuild such as `build` or `docbuild`.